# Finding periodic points of diffeomorphism of the circle

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems

I want to find all the periodic points of the following diffeomorphism of the circle:

$f(x) = x + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{10} \sin(8 \pi x) \mod 1$

Where a periodic point is $p$ such that $f^n(p) = p$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I have shown the rotation number $\rho (f) = \frac{1}{4}$ (I think) so I know that periodic points exist (as the rotation number is rational) but that none are fixed points, i.e. no such $p$ for $n = 1$ (as rotation number is not zero).

I tried working from the definition but I get a horrible nest of sine functions. In general finding periodic points of functions like this doesn't appear to be well documented in my course notes, the recommended book or indeed the internet (from what I can find) so any help at all would be appreciated. I'm looking for a general method, not just the solution for this specific diffeomorphism, but really any help is great.

This isn't homework if anyone was wondering, it's revision and I'm more interested in the mathematics behind the general method for a solution than getting the specific solution of this question. Hints definitely welcome.

EDIT: Forgot to add, as for a lift $F$ of $f$ we have $deg(f) = F(x + 1) - F(x) = 1$, we know the diffeomorphism is orientation preserving.

Comment: Apologies.

$f^n(p) = f(f( \dots (f(p)) \dots )$, i.e. $f$ applied $n$ times.

A lift $F$ of $f$ is a map such that $\pi \circ F = f \circ \pi$ where $\pi(x) = x \mod 1$, in the case of circle homeomorphisms like this $F$ will be a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself and $f$ is a function from $\frac{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}}$ to itself.

Comment: and you have shown that $f(x+k/4) = f(x)+k/4$. and the "lifts" are of the form $F(x) = x + \frac14 + \frac1{10} \sin(8 \pi x) + k$. but I don't see what it tells us on the fixed points of $p \to f^n(p)$

Comment: We can use the lift $F$ of $f$ to calculate the degree and rotation number of $f$ which tells us that there are periodic points ($f$ has periodic points if and only if $\rho (f)$ is rational) and that there are no periodic points for $n = 1$/fixed points (as $\rho(f) = \frac{1}{4} \neq 0$).

I can't see what the first part will tell us either, sadly. Working through would be fairly simple without the nested sine function, which can be bound but that doesn't seem to help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know what is the rotation number, there is simple way. Recall that the rotation number is $p/q$ with $p$ and $q$ coprime if and only if $f$ has a periodic point of period $q$. So you should concentrate on finding a point of period $4$, and a simple inspection shows $0$ has period $4$.

Other than that, the only question remaining is whether there are other orbits with period $4$ (for sure there are no orbits with other periods!). Indeed there are three other such orbits, that of $1/8$ and two others.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot.

Do you know where $\frac{p}{q}$ with $p$ and $q$ coprime if and only if $f$ has a periodic point of period $q$ comes from? I'm sure I'm missing something stupid.

Comment: Not immediate, depends on what you have shown and in what order. But it goes like this: $f$ has a $q$-periodic point if and only if the rotation number is $p/q$ for some $q$. In order that the period is $q$ it is thus necessary and sufficient that $p$ and $q$ are coprime, since otherwise $p/q$ could be written as $p'/q'$ with $q'<q$ (and you would have a $q'$-periodic point).

Comment: We have not directly stated the $p / q$ coprime argument, however I think I have created an equivalent argument (probably the same):

I have proven $\rho(f^n) = n \rho(f)$, that $\rho(f) = 0 \iff f$ has a fixed point and if $f$ has a periodic point of period $n$ then $f^n$ has a fixed point; so from this I can conclude that all periodic points of $f$ are of period $4$ (as any other value that gives $\rho(f^n) = 0$ is a multiple of 4). Does this argument hold (assuming $deg(f) = 1$)?

I'm not sure how you concluded that there are precisely 4 periodic points, I'll have a look.

Comment: So I found that $f^4$ has countably infinite fixed points, $\frac{m}{8} \forall m \in \mathbb{N}$, however you said there are only 4 periodic points of $f$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @D. P On your first comment: indeed, you can also proceed as you describe. On your second comment: I said that there are $4$ orbits of period $4$, which gives sixteen $4$-periodic points; the points of the form $m/8$ are not infinite, but $8$ (since they are computed$\bmod1$); so, besides these $8$ points there are $8$ more, which I obtained looking at the monotonicity between the "initial" ones, but the computations are very much complicated, and I cannot suggest any straightforward approach (other than drawing the graph of $f^4$).

Comment: Ah okay, that makes more sense (I can't believe I forgot the mod 1 part...).

Did you know before finding all the periodic points that there were going to be 16 (or 4 orbits of period 4) or did you conclude this by finding all the fixed points of $f^4$ from the graph?

Also a little off topic question (sorry!), in this context does the forward/backward time behaviour of a typical point refer to the behaviour of a non periodic point as we apply $f$ over and over (or $f^{-1}$ for backward)?

Thanks for all of your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I looked at the properties of $f^4$ before posting, but it would take too much time to write them and then still add them here. So, I do suggest plotting the graph. On your last question, there is really no notion of a typical point for an orientation-preserving circle homeomorphism, but if you are talking about Birkhoff averages all will converge to delta measures on periodic orbits, and so it would be better to consider the periodic points as typical points.

Comment: Okay thank you, I will plot the graph.

For the "typical" points, we do not cover Birkhoff averages or anything so I assume the question was just poorly worded; I'll check with the person who writes the example sheets.

Comment: Hi, late reply; have tried plotting but got nowhere. Plotting the graph of f, F, f^4 or F^4 doesn't really seem to help; all are essentially just the sine curve with a 1/10th amplitude going along the diagonal (i.e. along the line g(x) = x). I tried using approximation methods to find some periodic points / fixed points on all 4 graphs but it didn't really help. My lecturer says (for any periodic point x) "we have F^4(x)-x=n for some integer n and it follows that the rotation number is (F^4(x)-x)/n". I understand the first part but not the second, surely F^4(x) - x / n = 1 always?